# Error: JMX connector server communication error: service:jmx:rmi when stopping/shutdown Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx

Title says it all. Tomcat 8 (Java 8) is running on Linux. After the error message I see that java process is not killed. Is it a problem with JMX configuration or what?

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=55001 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=55002 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=xxxxx -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=36976):

> There isn't. The reason why this is happening is that when tomcat
>   starts, port 5555 (in this example) is bound.
>
> F**or shutdown, another jvm is launched and gets the same jmx
>   parameters. Therefore, it tries to bind to port 5555, too, fails and
>   shuts the jvm down.** The shutdown procedure isn't executed and thus
>   tomcat is still running.
>
> The only fix I could think of is to introduce yet another variable
>   that applies to start and run but not to stop.

I had to set JMX parameters as CATALINA_OPTS and not as JAVA_OPTS and it worked.